# Attempt to present UINavigationController whose view

Tags: ios, swift

AppDelegate

```
   initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")as! UIViewController
    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Takes me to LoginViewController

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CardsNavController") as? UIViewController

self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I click on the login button takes me to CardsViewController

```
func goToProfile(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
   pageController.goToPreviousVC()
```

}

Clicking on back button which is part of the UINavigationController runs goToProfile (above)  and takes me to ViewController.swift because that's where the pageController is declared.

```
let pageController = ViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)
```

The error shows up here

```
func goToPreviousVC() {
    //let currentControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
   if viewControllers.isEmpty   {

    setViewControllers([profileVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    pageController.presentViewController(profileVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 else {
    let previousVC = pageViewController(self,  viewControllerBeforeViewController: viewControllers[0] as! UIViewController)!
    setViewControllers([previousVC], direction:  UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x15ce314e0> on <MyApp.ViewController: 0x15cd2c6f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Basically the flow is like this  AppDelegate -> LoginViewController -> ViewController and I need to get to ProfileViewController.

ProfileView has ProfileNavController while CardsView has CardsNavController

ViewController has a storyboardID of pageController.

Both ProfileView and and CardsView are embedded within UINavigationControllers (hence the NavController extension).

The second time I run the app after a fresh install it works perfectly (all the controllers get loaded okay). Should I push viewControllers in AppDelegate?

[image: storybord]

Comment: please add a screenshot of your storyboard..

Comment: Hi Nishant I provided the screenshot

Comment: i think you need to create object for storyboard. and write this line before `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`. Moreover once check in storyboard you have give storyboardid's to all the viewcontrollers ?Moreover, where you call the method `go to previous vc`? try to change place of the method where you declared because sometimes before the method execute it will go to find the view controller.sometimes due to short declaration we also get error.

Comment: The viewControllers all have a storyboardID. The problem is the first time around it doesn't work the first time around , but on second run it works. Basically viewControllers array is empty the first time around but not on subsequent launches of the program.

Comment: Could you post the complete `goToPreviousVC` method ?

Comment: Originally the goToPreviousVC didn't have the if viewControllers.isEmpty , it would go straight to the body of else but since viewControllers array is empty the first time it gets pushed I decided to forcefully push the navigation controller...

Comment: I will spend some time to try to reproduce the issue by myself anyway, but it would be the best if you could provide a part of the source code of your project having this issue. Btw, I found and fixed the same issue before in my project

Comment: Unfortunately, the description in the question is confusing, it's very hard to tell what the context is for the operations. If you could share the important part of your code, eg. on github, it would be very easy for us to help you.

Comment: I am not been able to understand the question and the flow which you need. Can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code using Xcode 7, which may not be ideal for resolving this issue because I had to covert your code to Swift 2.0, but here was what I found out.

**ISSUE**

1. First time opening the app, this block:

   ```
   if currentUser() != nil {
       initialViewController = pageController
   }
   else {
       initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
   }

   self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
   ```

Will initialize `LoginViewController` and make it the current window's `rootViewController`. 
At this point there is no `pageController` initialized

2. When user taps on the button to go to the Profile screen, this method will be called

   func goToProfile(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
       pageController.goToPreviousVC() 
   }

At this point, pageController is initialized, and off course, there is NOTHING in the `viewControllers` array. Let's see what happen in the `goToPreviousVC` method:

Original method looks like this:

```
    let nextVC = pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfterViewController: viewControllers[0] as UIViewController)!
    setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

One thing you can see obviously is: calling `viewControllers[0]` could give you a crash because `viewControllers` is an empty array. 
If you use Swift 2.0, it doesn't even let you compile your code :)

**SOLUTION**

Let's go directly to the solution: Ensure that the `pageController` is available before trying to call it's viewControllers.

I blindly tried fixing you code in Swift 2.0 and found out that this method would work for you:

BEFORE: In `LoginViewController.swift` line 63

```
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CardsNavController") as? UIViewController

        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

AFTER: Let's fix it like this

```
    let navc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CardsNavController") as! UINavigationController
    if let viewControllers = pageController.viewControllers where viewControllers.count == 0 {
        pageController.setViewControllers([navc.viewControllers[0]], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    self.presentViewController(pageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's working well here and probably I don't need to show you how the screen transition should look like :)

[image]

In case you would like to have the fixed source code as well, please find it [HERE](https://github.com/dobaduc/SO-32594473). Basically I converted your code to Swift 2.0 and ignored unnecessary parts like Facebook authentication for faster investigation.

Good luck & Happy coding!

Comment: Hello Ducky there is no UINavigationController for viewController as seen in the pic. However I'm using viewController to direct the flow of the other viewControllers accordingly.  Are you saying viewController should be embedded as well? Because currently it is not.

Comment: Yes. If you intended to manipulate the navigation stack so that you can show something like a 'pop' transition effect, then using UINavigationController is certainly the best & safe choice. Anyway it would be nice if you could just provide a part of your code somewhere on GitHub, I am sure I can help you to fix the issue

Comment: Hi Ducky will add the links Thanks.

Comment: Haha... Too bad. I updated my Xcode to Xcode 7. Basically need to download the old Xcode to perfectly reproduce your issue ^_^; Give me a little time, I am on Silver Week vacation in Japan LoL

Comment: Are there many differences between Xcode 7 and 6.1+ ? Like in terms of making the code compatible?

Comment: Yes. Your code must be written in/converted to Swift 2.0 syntax otherwise nothing works

Comment: Thank you so much Ducky! Have 3 quick questions
a) Why there's nothing in the viewControllers array  the first time it runs?
b) What does navc.viewControllers[0]   contain in LoginViewController.swift?
c) Why can't I do the same thing but with ProfileNavController in CardsNavController file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You know I was on a long vacation ^^;   1. Can you go back to first point in my answer? It happened because the 'current user' was nil, thus the pageController wasn't initialized like you wished; 2. viewControllers[0] is simply the way to retrieve the rootViewController of the container, in this case it is the CardViewController; 3. Correct me if I didn't fully understand your question, but once you instantiate the hierachy correctly & access the viewControllers in the container when the container is ready, there should be no limitation to manipulate the hierarchy :)

Comment: Perfect thank you!  So basically it started with 'current user' being nil. Much appreciated